# Python: How would I find get a list of every character in a string?

Tags: python, string

For example:

```
>>> str = "aaabbc"
```

How would I get an output like this:

```
str.count(a) = 3
str.count(b) = 2
str.count(c) = 1
str.count(d) = 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is practically valid anyway (if inefficient).

Answer (score 9):

```
In [27]: mystr = "aaabbc"

In [28]: collections.Counter(mystr)
Out[28]: Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})

In [29]: dict(collections.Counter(mystr))
Out[29]: {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
```

Comment: worth noting counter comes in in 2.7 +

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for ltr in my_string:
    d[ltr] += 1

print d
```

this has been asked a few times before ...

here is an answer that works in python < 2.7

Comment: As long as OP isn't stuck with an archaic python2.4 :-p

Answer (score 1):

Considering you also want 0 returned for elements that are not in the string, you can try this:

```
def AnotherCounter (my_string, *args):
    my_dict = {ele : 0 for ele in args}
    for s in my_string:
        my_dict[s] +=1
    return my_dict
```

Result:

```
>>> AnotherCounter("aaabbc", 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
{'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions, you are not limited to a single character, though:

```
import re
p = re.compile("a")
len(p.findall("aaaaabc")) //5
```

If you want to find out more, visit here: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html.

Comment: this is almost certainly not the "right" way to do this (even if it works)

Comment: It's actually pretty right if he ever needs to count more than one character, or even better complex patterns. OP didn't really describe what he needed this for, so I'm just letting him know of a scaleable way of doing things.